# adding an operator to std::vector<T>

Tags: c++, operators

I am trying to add an operator to std::vector to identify when 2 vectors are approximately the same. How do I do it?

```
template<typename T> //only numeric types
class ImperciseVector: public std::vector<T> {
    public:
        ImperciseVector() {} //is this constructor needed?
        bool operator~ (const ImperciseVector& v) {
           T l1sq=0.0, l2sq=0.0, l3sq=0.0;

           if ((*this).size() != v.size() || (*this).size==0 || v.size()==0) return false; 
           for (int j = 0; j<(*this).size(); j++) {
               l1sq += (*this)[j]*(*this)[j];
               l2sq += v[j]*v[j];
               l3sq+= ((*this)[j]-v[j])*((*this)[j]-v[j]);
           }
           //some estimate such that length of their  their difference (relative to their size) is small enough
           if (l3sq/(l1sq*l2sq) <= 0.00001) return true; 
           return false;
        }
};
```

It does not work and does not even recognize when I write the operator what is ment. How to do it correctly or better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator~()` is a *unary* operator. It's usage can only be `~iv`, not `iv1 ~ iv2`. It'd be better to simply write a member function called something like `approx()` or overload `operator==` in this case (in does make sense, right? Two `ImpreciseVector`s are equal if they're approximately equal?)

Side-note, don't have `ImpreciseVector<T>` inherit from `vector<T>`. Use composition instead.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Now that I think of it the overloading  of operator== actually works, I was a bit hesitant to do so because it seemed they both take the same argumenttypes (which is not true) and the same nr. of arguments so it seemed ambiguous. How do you mean use composition instead? like class ImperciseVector<T>{ class std::vector<T>; bool operator==(...){...}}?

Comment: @Fr4ns Yes, that is composition.